# Digester Property value is not set in java

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, digest

Am having two properties of a bean but one is getting parsed value from XML and another is not getting using Digester in java Please help to solve this issue.

Output

```
podate:08021988:odate:null
```

XML File

```
    <Header>
    <PODate>08021988</PODate>
    <PODate1>08021988</PODate1>
    </Header>
```

Digester Setters

```
        digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "ECnetPO/Header/PODate","podate");
        digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "EcnetPO/Header/PODate1","podate1");
        digester.addSetNext( "ECnetPO/Header", "addPO" );
```

Print

```
 public void addPO( YESBarePO po ) {
        System.out.println("podate:"+po.getPodate()+":odate:"+po.getPodate1());
}
```

Bean Info

```
private String  podate;
private String  podate1;
public String getPodate()
{
    return podate;
}


public void setPodate(String podate)
{
    this.podate = podate;
}

public String getPodate1()
{
    return podate1;
}


public void setPodate1(String podate1)
{
    this.podate1 = podate1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with [Digester debugging output](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Digester/FAQ#How_do_I_enable_debugging_output_for_Digester.3F)?

Comment: I don't know that ,just came to know by you. will check that,Thanks for you valuable reply.